# Getting all the nodes in a specific level of a tree

Tags: c#

Given the following class, used to build a tree hierarchy:

```
public class simpletest
{
    public simpletest Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<simpletest> Children { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How could I get a list of all objects for a specific level?

Here is some sample data (hopefully its formatted correctly):

```
var root = new simpletest() { Name = "Root" };
var level1childA = new simpletest() { Name = "level1childA", Parent = root };
var level1childB = new simpletest() { Name = "level1childB", Parent = root };

var level2childA = new simpletest() { Name = "level2childA", Parent = level1childA };
var level2childB = new simpletest() { Name = "level2childB", Parent = level1childA };
var level2childC = new simpletest() { Name = "level2childC", Parent = level1childB };
var level2childD = new simpletest() { Name = "level3childD", Parent = level1childB };

var level3childA = new simpletest() { Name = "level3childA", Parent = level2childA };
var level3childB = new simpletest() { Name = "level3childB", Parent = level2childA };
var level3childC = new simpletest() { Name = "level3childC", Parent = level2childB };
var level3childD = new simpletest() { Name = "level3childD", Parent = level2childB };
var level3childE = new simpletest() { Name = "level3childE", Parent = level2childC };
var level3childF = new simpletest() { Name = "level3childF", Parent = level2childC };
var level3childG = new simpletest() { Name = "level3childG", Parent = level3childD };
var level3childH = new simpletest() { Name = "level3childH", Parent = level3childD };

level2childA.Children = new List<simpletest> { level3childA, level3childB };
level2childB.Children = new List<simpletest> { level3childC, level3childD };
level2childC.Children = new List<simpletest> { level3childE, level3childF };
level2childD.Children = new List<simpletest> { level3childG, level3childH };

level1childA.Children = new List<simpletest> { level2childA, level2childB };
level1childB.Children = new List<simpletest> { level2childC, level2childD };
```

So for example, using node level3childE, how would I get all the nodes from the same level? The node names can be anything.

Comment: Create a method `Depth` that for each node return its depth to the root? Then LINQ select on the root node with the appropriate query?

Comment: You could either create a Level/Depth property then query objects based on this property OR create a basic for loop which iteratres through your tree items to the desired level at which point it selects these objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an (untested) recursive approach implemented as a member function of simpletest:

```
IEnumerable<simpletest> ElementsAtDepth(int depth) {
    if(depth > 0) {
        foreach(simpletest child in this.Children)
            foreach(simpletest element in child.ElementsAtDepth(depth - 1))
                yield return element;
    }
    else {
        foreach(simpletest element in this.Children)
            yield return element;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks BlackBear, given my sample data above it does get all the nodes for the specified depth. I did noticed the results contain duplicates, for a depth of 1, two level1childA and two level1childB are returned. Also, if the depth is specified as 3, which is the bottom level and nodes have no children (leaf nodes?), this generates an error on the line "foreach(simpletest element in this.Children)".

Comment: @JohnSmith: I've spot a typo in my code, try now. As for the error I believe it happens because Children is null, you should therefore initialize it in the costructor.

Comment: this returns the children of elements at depth and cannot return the root.

Answer (score 0):

BlackBear's solution returns the next level down and cannot return the root/initial node which may be useful for binding. 
The code below will give you nodes at the level requested.
Note also that depth is relative to the initial node and not the actual tree.

```
public IEnumerable<simpletest> NodesAtDepth(int depth)
{
    if (depth <= 0 )
        yield return this;
    else if (depth > 1)
    {
        if (this.Children != null)
            foreach (simpletest child in this.Children)
                foreach (simpletest element in child.NodesAtDepth(depth - 1))
                    yield return element;
    }
    else
    {
        if (this.Children != null)
            foreach (simpletest element in this.Children)
                yield return element;
    }
}
```